# Float Precision Display (Android)

Tags: android, floating-point, precision

I am trying to make a program that takes some user input, runs a few calculations and outputs the answer. My problem is that this answer is sometimes many decimal places long which is causing some aesthetic and layout problems.  I only need to display 4 decimal places worth of data. Is there anyway to limit the precision of these numbers at output time? (The Numbers are stored in floats and I'm programming for Android.)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can format a float to 4 decimal places using `String.format`.

Example:

```
String result = String.format("%.4f", theNumber);
```

See also:

- [How to nicely format floating numbers to String without unnecessary decimal 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-types-to-string)
- [String.format(format, args)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)
- [Format strings in Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)