# Is possible to use apfloat library in android applications?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apfloat

I am working on android app. (eclipse kepler) in which i want to use 3rd party library Apfloat.
I have configured build path and references for external library (30 times), restarted, cleaned, rebuilded every time, imported org.apfloat.Apfloat;, used diferent versions of apfloat library and tryed solutions from this topic:

[a link][NoClassDefFoundError - Eclipse and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247998/noclassdeffounderror-eclipse-and-android)

but, my app is still crashing. So can be Apfloat lib used for android app development and i am just unclucky to confire it right. or Apfloat can't be used for adroid app at all.

Answer (score -1):

Android doesnt support it i guess.

maybe this solution can be usefull for u

[[Float Precision Display (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774087/float-precision-display-android][1])