# Removing the .0 from a double

Tags: java, double, long-integer

I am trying to display numbers in a string dynamically, so if the number has decimal's display them but if not don"t show the .0

example: display 5.5 as 5.5 and 5.0 as 5

This is what I have so far: (answer is a double)

```
double temp = answer;
long temp2 = (long) temp;
if (temp == temp2) {
output = String.valueOf(temp2);
System.out.println(output);
```

this work's fine up to about 1e18 then will error out because of the maximum size of a Long.
So how would I achieve this on bigger numbers like 5.43e86

Comment: Why don't you use DecimalFormat ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to nicely format floating types to String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-types-to-string)

Comment: @EJP Math.floor() also returns a double, so .0 will remain.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

```
double answer = 5.0;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.#");
System.out.println(df.format(answer));
```

Comment: I think you mean `new DecimalFormat("###");` because he does not want to see the digits after decimal dot.

Comment: Thanks! I am using devimalformat elsewhere in my application. Should have thought of that. great answer.

Comment: @AlexR -- That will print 5 ( instead of 5.0 ) and 5.5 if answer = 5.5.

Comment: -1, # is "Digit, zero shows as absent", which will still print the 0 after the decimal. Not what he asks

Comment: @Greg -- I suggest you try the code above. It does exactly what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 2):

The DecimalFormat suggestions are the easiest way to handle this.  If they aren't sufficient, here's another idea.

If you're starting to hit the maximum values that can be represented by primitives in Java, then you may need to move to [BigInteger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) and [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Try playing around with the `BigDecimal.toBigInteger()` method coupled with the `toString()` methods on BigDecimal and BigInteger.

Answer (score 2):

**It's not good solution**
if you use new DecimalFormat("0.#") you are missing data, for example 
PI = 3.14, but after parse you ae geting 3.1

Another solution to use eval%1 ?  (int)d : d 
this time couse max integer limit , again missing data

my solution is working, but it's not good idea

```
res = removeLastChars(eval,".0");

private String removeLastChars(double eval, String text){

    String res = String.valueOf(eval);
    int length = text.length();

    if (res.length() > length){
        res = res.substring((res.length() - length), res.length()).equals(text)
                ? res.substring(0, (res.length() - length)) : res;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Apache commons-lang:

```
StringUtils.removeEnd(String.valueOf(100d), ".0")
```

gives you "100" instead of "100.0":

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

System.out.println(String.valueOf(100d)); // output is "100.0"
System.out.println(StringUtils.removeEnd(String.valueOf(100d), ".0")); // output is "100"
```

Answer (score -3):

Look at 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

you would want just DecimalFormat("0.0")

Comment: This will print `5.0` or `5,0` with German Locale (Java build 1.6.0_24-b07)