# Remove '.0' from double, but keep every other possibility

Tags: java, formatting, double

I've seen a bunch of questions here on Stackoverflow referring to hiding the `.0` after a double, but every single answer says to use DecimalFormat and do `#.#` to hide it. Except this is not what I want.

For every single possibility where the double does NOT end in simply `.0`, I want them to be how they are. Except when it DOES end in `.0`, remove it. In other words, I want to keep my precision at all times, unless it ends with a `.0`.

Examples:

```
0.0000000000000000042345470000230 -> 0.0000000000000000042345470000230
0.4395083451 -> 0.4395083451
46547453.00024235 -> 46547453.00024235

435.0 -> 435
```

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Further example:

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109388/removing-the-0-from-a-double?rq=1) has the type of answer I am talking about:

> Use DecimalFormat
>
> ```
> double answer = 5.0;
> DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.#");
> System.out.println(df.format(answer));
> ```

The `###.#` above means that I am going to have the first 3 digits appear, a period, and then the first number after it. Regardless of my value, only the first fractional number will be formatted.

Comment: Why the downvote? There is nothing off-topic about the question as it refers to programming. Also, there's no "minimal verifiable example" because I have no idea how to code this.

Comment: it is a problem about formatting and not about a specific data type.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The examples are purely ***examples***. The stupidity of length of the numbers I provided are just extreme examples to show that they simply **do not** end with a `.0`. I know their not *actually* represented as is.

Comment: @Euclides As for the datatype, I added `double` as a tag, because it refers to formatting that specific dataype. Would you like me to change it?

Comment: You check for the exactly-zero case by checking `myDouble == (long) myDouble`, as long as the double is less than 2^53 (and if it's bigger, the fractional part is zero by definition). With that info, do you have enough to get the rest?

Comment: @yshavit Ah, alright. I normally see casts to `int`, but I see what your getting at here. Thanks, lets see how I go.

Comment: @frayment it is not an issue about the data type per se, there is nothing wrong using double, but what are you trying to do? if you want to display 5.0 as 5 then you would type: if (5.0 % 1 == 0) then format it as just #.

Comment: @Euclides I'm literally just trying to remove the trailing zeros, ONLY if theres nothing but zeros. If you look at yshavit's comment, whats the benefit of using modulo over casts, and vice versa?

Comment: You're assuming that floating point numbers can act like decimal numbers, and the truth is -- they can't.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I only want to make them act like one when I'm formatting string-wise though?

Comment: This is not how floating point numbers work. Seriously.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Of course not! :) I'm working on a library that does ridiculously accurate calculations, but can't stand having that `.0` printed when I have a whole number.

Comment: But **again** your concept of "whole" numbers has no meaning when it comes to floating point numbers.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sorry, I don't understand what your trying to tell me? I know what a whole number is, and the logic behind floating-point numbers?

Comment: @frayment you are a bit confused,  if you want to manage a double as an integer then you have the wrong approach.  If you are using it for calculations then keep using the float numbers as they are.  Then, if you need to print it into a report/user interface, then format it using some cool class as DecimalFormat.

Comment: @Euclides But my question refers to not using `DecimalFormat` for the exact reason why someone would use it. If I use the `#.#` formatting, I only keep my precision to one decimal place! That is not what I am after.

Comment: You remain greatly confused about how floating point numbers work in not only Java but all digital computers. That's the crux of this question since in floating point numbers `.0` really has no meaning.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ... I understand that it has no meaning, because without it the fundamental meaning of a floating point number is lost. That is not my question. My question, is how, to remove the meaningless `.0` from a string!

Comment: Got it, it is time to start to use BigDecimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well actually it's not complicated at all. Just check this (It even gives you the most precise number):

```
//Square root of 5 will give you a lot of decimals    
BigDecimal d1 = new BigDecimal(sqrt(5));
//5 will give you none
BigDecimal d2 = new BigDecimal(5);
//Print and enjoy
System.out.println(d1.stripTrailingZeros());
System.out.println(d2.stripTrailingZeros());
```

The `stripTrailingZeros()` will remove any trail of plain 0's, but keep the formatting if other numbers are present.

Comment: Oh my god, the precision on that thing. :O

Comment: Alright, I've just tried it, and have had to set the precision on it with `setScale` because the numbers I am using are so massively long. I used `d = d.setScale(10, RoundingMode.FLOOR);` on a number, and it is now equal to `500.0000000000`. I print this, and the trailing zeros are still there?

Comment: again,  it is just a question of perception, print d.intValue() and you will obtain 500.

Comment: @Euclides Yes but that is not what I am after. That would still remove my decimal trailings. I found the answer anyway, just use `skipTrailingZeros()`.

Comment: Great! I am glad you found it finally.

Comment: is it skipTrailingZeros()?  I have stripTrailingZeros().

Comment: stripTrailingZeros() in did

Comment: Woops! stripTrailingZeros() it is! Did that one without looking. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @frayment I also found a library to read [Quadruple-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format) that's the biggest precision you can get if you are interested... Just follow [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21071907/3571692) to the answer I found