# Why do some floating point numbers appear with a trailing 0

Tags: java, floating-point, render-to-string

Does anyone know why the numbers 0.001 to 0.009 are rendered to a String with a trailing 0 but other numbers do not. e.g. numbers 0.01 to 0.09 do not.

```
System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());
for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
    System.out.println(i / 1e3);
```

prints

```
en_GB
0.0
0.0010
0.0020
0.0030
0.0040
0.0050
0.0060
0.0070
0.0080
0.0090
0.01
0.011
0.012
0.013
0.014
0.015
0.016
0.017
0.018
0.019
0.02
```

---

EDIT The code for DecimalFormat doesn't appear to be locale dependant. If I run

```
for (Locale l : Locale.getAvailableLocales())   {
    Locale.setDefault(l);
    System.out.println(l + " " + 1 / 1e3);
}
```

on Java 6 update 26 on Ubuntu 11.04 I get

```
ja_JP 0.0010
es_PE 0.0010
en 0.0010
... many locales with the same result ...
sv_SE 0.0010
da_DK 0.0010
es_HN 0.0010
```

on Java 7 on same system I get

```
ms_MY 0.001
ar_QA 0.001
is_IS 0.001
... many locales with the same result ...
el_CY 0.001
hu 0.001
fr_FR 0.001
```

Comment: Hmm... I don't get that behaviour. I get "0.001" etc. What locale are you in?

Comment: I am getting this behaviour, fr_CH, but I get it with Locale.US as well.

Comment: May be the JVM, I'm using Windows7 jdk 1.6.22

Comment: @Matthew: Interesting. I'm using JDK 7 on Windows 7, btw.

Comment: same as @JonSkeet with Ubuntu 10.10, JDK 1.6.0_20

Comment: The DecimalFormat class doesn't appear to be locale dependant. This happens with Java 6 update 26, but not Java 7 on Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: I get same as Peter, en_AU, java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: I don't get trailing zeroes with JDK 7 on Win XP with locale `Locale loc = Locale.forLanguageTag("hi"); Locale.setDefault(loc);`. EDIT: I also don't get it for en_US. EDIT 2: As a matter of fact, I don't get trailing zeroes for *any* locale.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This was identified as a bug in Java 1.3 - Java 6:  http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4428022‎

EDIT:  As to *why* this happens, here's the fix referred to in the bug report that was ported from OpenJDK 6: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/rev/8159687b6316

Turns out it's an off-by-one error.  (The fix changes <= to <).

Comment: A bug it appears it took them ten years to fix. :P

Comment: Tracked down the patch that fixed this (info added to the answer).

Answer (score 4):

For those interested, [here is a diff](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java/?v=diff&id2=6-b14) between the FloatingDecimal class responsible for creating the string representation of the double. As you can see from the diff, the patch fixes the special case encountered when the exponent is -3 in the dtoa() method.