# in Java, how to delete all 0s in float?

Tags: java, floating-point, zero

I'd like to change float like this way:

10.5000 -> 10.5
10.0000 -> 10

How can I delete all zeros after the decimal point, and change it either float (if there's non-zeros) or int (if there were only zeros)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't quite understand. The zeros are just a product of the textual representation, they have nothing to do with how the float is internally represented. Are you looking for custom output formats suppressing trailing zeros?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why not try regexp?

```
new Float(10.25000f).toString().replaceAll("\\.?0*$", "")
```

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense because `new Float(10.25000f).toString()` already gives you "10.25" so `.replaceAll("0*$", "")` is of no use.

Comment: `"\.0+$"` if you want to also get rid of the period.

Comment: If I change "0*$" to "\.0+$", it says "unexpected char: '.'" - I'm on Processing actually.

Comment: @user1076206 Must escape the backslash, "\\.0+$".

Comment: Thanks Daniel, it worked. I also used replaceAll("0*$", "").replace(".", " "). Actually for visual reason, I added a white space at the end.

Answer (score 18):

Well the trick is that floats and doubles themselves don't really have trailing zeros per se; it's just the way they are printed (or initialized as literals) that might show them.  Consider these examples:

```
Float.toString(10.5000); // => "10.5"
Float.toString(10.0000); // => "10.0"
```

You can use a [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to fix the example of "10.0":

```
new java.text.DecimalFormat("#").format(10.0); // => "10"
```

Comment: +1 for DecimalFormat. Additionally decimal format using half even rounding. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not clarify that I was actually working on Processing. The regexp was simpler flor my case.

Answer (score 2):

This handles it with two different formatters:

```
double d = 10.5F;
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0");
DecimalFormat decimalFormatter = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
String s;
if (d % 1L > 0L) s = decimalFormatter.format(d);
else s = formatter.format(d);

System.out.println("s: " + s);
```

Answer (score 2):

java.math.BigDecimal has a stripTrailingZeros() method, which will achieve what you're looking for.

```
BigDecimal myDecimal = new BigDecimal(myValue);
myDecimal.stripTrailingZeros();
myValue = myDecimal.floatValue();
```

Answer (score 2):

**You just need to use format class like following:**

```
new java.text.DecimalFormat("#.#").format(10.50000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Format your numbers for your output as required. You cannot delete the internal "0" values.

Answer (score 0):

Try using System.out.format

Heres a link which allows c style formatting
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and find a workaround in the following link:
[StackOverFlow - How to nicely format floating numbers to string without unnecessary decimal 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0)

The answer from JasonD was the one I followed. It's not locale-dependent which was good for my issue and didn't have any problem with long values.

Hope this help.

ADDING CONTENT FROM LINK ABOVE:

```
public static String fmt(double d) {
    if(d == (long) d)
        return String.format("%d",(long)d);
    else
        return String.format("%s",d);
    }
```

Produces:

```
232
0.18
1237875192
4.58
0
1.2345
```

Comment: Can you add some content from the link?