# Why does my code always go to the else statement?

Tags: java, string, if-statement

```
package GC;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Calculate exam grade needed(e) or final grade received(f)?");
    String x = input.nextLine();
    if (x == "e"){
        double q1, q2, f, e;
        Scanner inputa = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner inputb = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner inputc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Quarter 1: ");
        q1 = inputa.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Quarter 2: ");
        q2 = inputb.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Final grade wanted: ");
        f = inputc.nextInt();

        e = 5*(f-0.4*(q1)-0.4*(q2));
        if(e == (int)e){
            System.out.println((int)e);
        }
        else{
            e = 0.01*((int)(e*100));
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }


    else if (x == "f"){

    }
    else{
        System.out.println("ERROR");
    }



}
}
```

Even if I input e at the beginning, it always goes to the else statement. I may have done something wrong with getting a String from user input or with my if parameters. What am I missing?

Comment: try reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-types-to-string and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the "equals" compare method. X is a string and there is no overloading operator for "==" on it to compare values.

Always take a look at the javadocs for an object if you're unsure.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

```
if(x.equals("e")){

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (x == "e"){
```

You should compare `String` objects with [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and not `operator==`. You should also be aware of [`equalsIgnoreCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29), which checks for equality of `String`s, while ignoring which case each character is - it might be useful sometimes.

`operator==` checks for *identity* - if the two objects are actually the same object [the variables referencing the same object], while `equals()` is checking for *equality* - if their content is the same.

change

```
if (x == "e"){
```

to

```
if ("e".equals(x)) {
```

and do the same for `else if (x == "f"){`

Comment: If there is an error in the Java VM. In general though, this is the proper convention to perform the method on the constant.

Comment: @Legend: If there is an error in the JVM - nothing is predictable. I approved your edit, because it may be a *better practice* but it is definetly not *wrong*.

Answer (score 0):

Because `e` is double and when you cast it to `int` you lose some bits.

Comment: that makes no sense, e is a variable from inside the if

Comment: No, the statement you are refering to: `if(e == (int)e){` is most likely unreachable with this piece of code.

Comment: pieces like `e == (int)e` should sound strange. The intention is "if e  has no fractional part, then do A, else do B". A will print `e` which is expected to have no fractional part, while the intention of B, it seems it's to have 2 digits after the decimal point. It is the *wrong* way to do it. First, being `e` the result of several floating point operations, it is likely always != from `(int)e`. Then, you have to learn how to format numbers to string, or round them properly with the desidered "precision".

Answer (score 0):

try (maybe you are getting a blank space:

```
String x = input.nextLine().toString().trim()
```

or

```
x.equals("e")
```