# How to remove the decimal part from a float number that contains .0 in java

Tags: java, android

I just want to remove the fractional part of a float number that contains **.0**. All other numbers are acceptable..
For example :

```
  I/P: 1.0, 2.2, 88.0, 3.56666, 4.1, 45.00 , 99.560
  O/P: 1 ,  2.2, 88,   3.567,   4.1, 45 ,    99.560
```

Is there any method available to do that **other than** "*comparing number with ".0" and taking substring*" ?

EDIT :
 I don't want ACTING FLOAT NUMBERs (like 1.0, 2.0 is nothing but 1 2 right?)

I feel my question is  little confusing...
Here is my clarification: I just want to display a series of floating point numbers to the user. If the fractional part of a number is zero, then display only the integer part, otherwise display the number as it is. I hope it's clear now..

Comment: "Comparing number with ''.0'' and taking substring" won't convert "45.00" to "45".  Do you want to strip an arbitrary number of zeroes from the end?

Comment: Have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-types-to-string

Comment: Do you have to keep the trailing 0 on '99.560' or would '99.56' be OK?

Comment: Post some source code. Your question is meaningless without it.

Comment: @ NickT it doesnt matter i only integer in integer format. i dont want ACTING FLOAT NUMBER (like 1.0, 2.0 is nothing but 1 2 right?)

Comment: @ EJP i dont want ACTING FLOAT NUMBERs (like 1.0, 2.0  is nothing but 1 2 right?)

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What I meant was that for all the i/ps and required o/ps you have listed, then  IF for an i/p of 99.560 an o/p of 99.56 was acceptable, then a simple NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###.###"), would give you what you require. (all other o/ps would be as you have listed them)

Comment: @vnshetty: In what way does your statement constitute posting source code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use a regular expression such as this: `\\.0+$`. If there are only 0's after the decimal point this regular expression will yield true.

Another thing you could do is something like so:

```
float x = 12.5;
float result = x - (int)x;
if (result != 0)
{
    //If the value of `result` is not equal to zero, then, you have a decimal portion which is not equal to 0.
}
```

Comment: thanks for that, fast and efficient ^^
 Under Android i did     Float remains = floatval - FloatMath.floor(floatval);

Answer (score 18):

If android gives you lemons. Dont throw it.

```
YourFormatedStringNumber = NumberFormat.getInstance().format(myNumber);

makes -> "12.50" to "12.50"  and "12.00" to "12"
```

[More here in doc.](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html)

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do ! Fantastic

Answer (score 13):

Try:

```
String.format("%.0f",value);
```

Comment: Did not help. It still keeps the zeros.

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment yet so just a heads up.
number value needs to be a double for it to work.

```
String.format("%.0f", number)
```

Answer (score 2):

try [NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) or even [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

> If you want to not show a decimal point where there might be no digits
>   after the  decimal point, use setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown.

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically the display part is text, so you could do it with regular expression.  If the number matches then use groups to extract the correct part. (I'll update the post with a solution later.)

Alternatively, you could simply go:

```
if ((int)Math.round(number) == number) {
   System.out.println((int) number)  
} else {
   System.out.println(number)  
}
```

or even:

```
System.out.println((int) Math.round(number) == number ? 
    String.valueOf((int) number) : String.valueOf(number));
```

careful, the String.valueOf() is required, as this does not work.  The System.out.println(double) will always get executed, i.e. the below does not work:

```
System.out.println((int)Math.round(number) == number ? (int) number : number);
```

Comment: -1 your final print statement (with the tertiary operator) doesn't work because `println(double)` will always be invoked.

Comment: I don't understand... how do you get that?

Answer (score 0):

try casting int before the float number

Comment: Please See this first before answering. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I've created this extension method. if amount contains decimal(40.01) it will show decimal other wise it will show only amount(40.00)

1. input 2000.43, Result = 2,000.43
2. input 2000.00, Result = 2,000

   ```
    fun Double.FormattedAmount(): String {

       val otherSymbols = DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US)
       val decimalFormat = DecimalFormat("#,###,###.##", otherSymbols)
       return decimalFormat.format(this).toString()

    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple for kotlin

```
float number = 12.5
number.toInt()
```