# Remove trailing zeros from double

Tags: java, double, decimalformat

I would like to remove all trailing zeros without truncating or rounding the number if it doesn't have any. For example, the number could be something like `12.0`, in which case, the trailing zero should be removed. But the number could also be something **almost** irrational, like `12.9845927346958762...` going on an on to the edge of the screen. Is there a way to setup DecimalFormat or some other class to cut of trailing zeros, while keeping the irrationality intact?

Comment: A double cannot represent an irrational value...

Comment: A DecimalFormat with `0.###` will do such a thing. Of course `double` is just an approximation of floating point numbers. Maybe use BigDecimal, but that also is a final class.

Comment: @JoopEggen the zero before the decimal point would allow for more than the units place, such as something like 234123412.1? Sorry, I have never used DecimalFormat before.

Comment: Yes, and BTW a DecimalFormat does not modify the original value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-types-to-string

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you are willing to switch to `BigDecimal`, there is a [#stripTrailingZeroes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros%28%29) method that accomplishes this.

Comment: Does that affect the resulting string representation?

Comment: But wouldn't that put a number like 600.0 in scientific notation?

Comment: @Jesse Rusak: Yes.
@Mohit: Not if you use `#toPlainString()` for output.

Answer (score 6):

You can use String manipulation to remove trailing zeros.

```
private static String removeTrailingZeros(double d) {
  return String.valueOf(d).replaceAll("[0]*$", "").replaceAll(".$", "");
}

System.out.println(removeTrailingZeros(1234.23432400000));
System.out.println(removeTrailingZeros(12.0));
```

Comment: I think last "replace" should be more like:
.replaceAll("\\.$", "");

Answer (score 6):

> private static String removeTrailingZeros(double d) {
>     return String.valueOf(d).replaceAll("[0]*$", "").replaceAll(".$", "");
>   }

or

> private static String removeTrailingZeros(double d) {
>    return String.valueOf(d).replaceAll(".?0*$", "");
>   }

These are wrong code.

> System.out.println(removeTrailingZeros(*1234.23432***400000**));
>   return: **1234.23432**  
>   but must return: *1234.23432***4**

---

> private static String removeTrailingZeros(double myDouble) {
>     return (new BigDecimal(Double.toString(myDouble))).toPlainString().replaceAll("[0]
> *$", "").replaceAll(".$", "");
>   }

This method is working wrong too

> System.out.println(removeTrailingZeros(**472.304000**));
>   returns **472.30**  instead of **472.304**
>
> System.out.println(removeTrailingZeros(**472304000**));
>   returns **47230**  instead of **472304000**

The  #stripTrailingZeroes() or toPlainString() of the BigDecimal are good method, but nor alone.

**//----------------BigDecimal.toPlainString-------------** 

System.out.println((new BigDecimal(Double.toString(**4724**))).toPlainString());
System.out.println((new BigDecimal(Double.toString(**472304000**))).toPlainString());

returns:
4724.0  (this is not fine - we don't want '.0')
472304000 (This is fine)

**//----------------BigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros-------------**

System.out.println((new BigDecimal(Double.toString(**4724**)).stripTrailingZeros()));
System.out.println((new BigDecimal(Double.toString(**472304000d**)).stripTrailingZeros()));

returns:
**4724.0**  (This is fine)
**4.72304E+8** (This is not fine - we want **472304000**)

The perfect resolution of the currect subject "Remove trailing zeros from double" is using 
 .stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString()

For example :
**//---------BigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros.toPlainString-----------------**

System.out.println(new BigDecimal(Double.toString(**472.304000**)).stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString());
System.out.println((new BigDecimal(Double.toString(**4724**)).stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString()));
System.out.println((new BigDecimal(Double.toString(**472304000d**)).stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString()));

Result is:
**472.304**   (correct)
**4724**      (correct)
**472304000** (correct)

Comment: Please edit the code blocks according to [help document](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). In most cases, you don't actually need HTML tags.

Answer (score -3):

```
double result = ...;
int intResult = (int)result;
if (result == intResult) {
    System.out.println(intResult);
} else {
    System.out.println(result);
}
```