# How to remove trailing zeros from a double

Tags: java, double, zero, trailing

For example I need `5.0` to become `5`, or `4.3000` to become `4.3`.

Comment: Note: Unlike the top answer in the linked question, all of these answers rely on an expected input of only one decimal place. Everything longer than one decimal place will be rounded, which may not be desired behaviour.

Comment: This is ugly as hell but it works: String.format(doubleVal).replaceAll("\\.0+$", "");

Comment: P.S. Ended up using this: DecimalFormat("#.################").format(doubleVal); // This ensures no trailing zeroes and no separator if fraction part is 0 (there's a special method setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(false) for that, but it seems to be already disabled by default). But will produce up to 16 digits of fractional part (and you can put more # there if you think 16 is not enough).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

```
  double answer = 5.0;
   DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.#");
  System.out.println(df.format(answer));
```

Comment: Won't this round the numnber like in case of 5.000001

Comment: It does and that's why this is wrong...

Answer (score 108):

You should use `DecimalFormat("0.#")`

---

For `4.3000`

```
Double price = 4.3000;
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.#");
System.out.println(format.format(price));
```

output is:

```
4.3
```

---

In case of 5.000 we have

```
Double price = 5.000;
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.#");
System.out.println(format.format(price));
```

And the output is:

```
5
```

Comment: this fails the case of `5.0` becoming `5`, as it will always add a `.0` to the end of numbers.

Comment: Thank you for Your comment. Now I have figured out that I should have used 0.#.

Comment: this fails in the case of `4.32` which becomes `4.3`

Comment: @DavidConrad yes, because it is specifying only one decimal digit precision

Comment: @Chisko The question asks how to "remove trailing zeros".

Comment: But the description clarifies

Comment: It fails, 4.300001 becomes 4.3 and if you want to convert it to double, it will add .0 again.

Comment: be aware that the output is 4,3 and not 4.3

Comment: A double type can't really do this. If you're willing to switch to BigDecimal, [here's the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11284983/365837).

Comment: But how to be with values like 0.0005000 (must shown as 0.0005)?

Answer (score 1):

Use a DecimalFormat object with a format string of "0.#".

Comment: this fails in the case of 4.32 which becomes 4.3

Comment: fair point, although the OP didn't indicate how many places were desired. I can't think of a good reason to truncate trailing 0's but keep non-zeros as far as they are printable. IMHO, when printing a double, the code should specify the desired number of digits of precision (the number of #'s after the period).

Comment: @Karoly DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        System.err.println(df.format(4.325));
        System.err.println(df.format(4.30));
        System.err.println(df.format(4.00));

Comment: @dashrb The OP was very explicit about what he wanted. He wants to remove trailing zeroes. Do you understand what the word "trailing" means?

Comment: @UncleIroh FYI this provides correct solution even after removing the RoundingMode.HALF_UP but keeping #.###

Comment: "0.##" will return 4.32 and not round off value.