# Java calculator debugging

Tags: java, casting, jframe, int

I am learning Java by debugging programs from various tutorials. At a moment I am fixing this calculator: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/321933-creating-a-calculator-using-jframe/
If you press "1/1" it displays "1.0" instead of "1". I am leaning towards

```
if (abs(result-round(result)) < 0.000000001){(int)(result)}
```

What would be an appropriate way to fix this glitch?
Thank you in advance,

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204905/java-how-to-remove-trailing-zeros-from-a-double

Comment: `(int)(result)` is meaningless. Do you mean `result=(int)(result);`?

Comment: Yes, I mean result=(int)(result);. Is there a better way to achieve this? I am trying to learn good coding practices.

Comment: @StepanLenevich if you do `(int)(result);` you don't get 1.5 for 3/2

Comment: That is why I am checking for if (abs(result-round(result)) < 0.000000001)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are close to what you want, but this code is probably the more correct way to do it:

```
if (abs(result-round(result)) < 0.000000001){(int)Math.round(result);}
```