# Either showing maximum number of decimal places, or don't show at all

Tags: java, android

Currently, using `DecimalFormat` I would like to show maximum number of decimal places, or don't show at all. For instance,

1. 100.0 shown as **"100"**
2. 100.123 shown as **"100.123"**
3. 100.123456789012345 shown as **"100.123456789012345"**
   Using format as

`new DecimalFormat("0.###");` is partially correct. It works for 1st case, 2nd case but not 3rd case. As, I have no idea how much `#` should I have?

So, may I know what is the correct `DecimalFormat` I should use?

Comment: So you'd want 100.12 to be shown as 100.120?

Comment: 100.12 should displayed as 100.12. I revised my question

Comment: similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-types-to-string

Comment: Can't you just do something like `if ((int)d == d) { // print (int)d } else { //print d }`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`setMaximumFractionDigits()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setMaximumFractionDigits%28int%29) to do this. The maximum value is `340`, so might as well set it to that value:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat();
    formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(340);
    BigDecimal[] numbers = {new BigDecimal("100.0"), new BigDecimal("100.123"), new BigDecimal("100.123456789012345")};
    for (BigDecimal number : numbers) {         
        System.out.println(formatter.format(number));
    }
}
```

prints

```
100
100.123
100.123456789012345
```

Comment: @YanChengCHEOK: Not according to the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setMaximumFractionDigits(int)). You're probably thinking of the maximum integer digits setting.