# Double to String, how to delete 0 after dot

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to nicely format floating types to String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-types-to-string)

I have number:

```
Double d1=(Double)0;
Double d2=(Double)2.2;
Double d3=(Double)4;
```

When I use to String, I get 0.0, 2.2, 4.0, but I want to see 0, 2.2, 4.
How can I do it?

Comment: What you meant by **When I use to String**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `DecimalFormat.format` insted of `Double.toString`:

```
Double d1 = (Double)0.0;
Double d2 = (Double)2.2;
Double d3 = (Double)4.0;

// Example: Use four decimal places, but only if required
NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.####");

String s1 = nf.format(d1); // 0
String s2 = nf.format(d2); // 2.2
String s3 = nf.format(d3); // 4
```

You don't even need `Double`s for that, `double`s will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

> First Convert your Double to String with String.valueof(YOUR_VARIABLE)

then Use Below Function to do it.

```
private String getyourNumber(String NUMBER) {
    if(!NUMBER.contains(".")) {
        return NUMBER;
    }

    return NUMBER.replaceAll(".?0*$", "");
}
```

then Convert your

> String to Double with `Double.parseDouble(YOUR_RETURNED_STRING)`.