# Remove trailing zeroes after decimal from double

Tags: java, double

I am writing a program to get the average of two numbers. For test case, `2, 4` the output should be `3` not `3.0`. For test case, `-1282660896,  -672813783`
 the output should be `-977737339.5` not `-9.777373395E8`.

My code is like this:

```
public static void getAve(long a, long b){
     System.out.println((double)(a + b) / 2);
}
```

I also created a format function to meet my need, like this:

```
public static String fmt(double d) {
        if (d == (long) d)
            return String.format("%d", (long) d);
        else
            return String.format("%s", d);
    }
```

But this also fails for test case 2

Comment: You need a format which doesn't switch to scientific notation.  I suggest you look at the others, or use `new DecimalFormat("0.#").format(d)`

Comment: You can keep the DecimalFormat object as a constant to improve performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case, you can do `String.format("%d", (int)d)` but only in the case if d doesn't have a decimal part.

Actually there is already an answer for that:

[How to nicely format floating numbers to String without unnecessary decimal 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0)

Comment: If you're going to cast a double to `int`, you'll lose the data after the comma altogether.

Comment: true, you can only do it in that special case when there is no decimal part.

Answer (score 0):

For the case 2, you want to use a format that doesn't use scientific notation and specify the precision:

```
return String.format("%.1f", d);  // only one digit fractional precision
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Also, comparing double to int is dangerous, since double is not guaranteed to represent exactly an integer. You'd better check if it close to an integer up to a predefined epsilon.