# Handling With Double In Computations(Java)

Tags: java, double, decimal, output

For a simple calculation like:

```
1+1 = 2.0
```

I'm not sure how to get rid of the unnecessary `.0` after the `2` integer, even though I'm working with a double variable as my output.
So, `1.1 + 1 = 2.1` is acceptable.

My output code looks like this:

```
        double total = 1+1;        
        output.setText(String.valueOf(total));
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14126736/1611791).

Answer (score 3):

Use `java.text.NumberFormat` or `String.format()`, e.g.:

```
output.setText(String.format("%.0f", total));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also check with modulo for the value after the . , but I think you should work with the other solution mentioned by @MoritzPetersen .

```
           double total = 1+1.1;        
            if((total%1) == 0) {
                System.out.println((String.valueOf(total)).split("\\.")[0]);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println((String.valueOf(total)));
            }
```