# How to remove trailing zero in a String value and remove decimal point

Tags: java, string, int, double

How do I remove trailing zeros in a String value and remove decimal point if the string contains only zeros after the decimal point?
I'm using the below code:

```
String string1 = Double.valueOf(a).toString()
```

This removes trailing zeros in (10.10 and 10.2270), but I do not get my expected result for 1st and 2nd inputs.

Input

```
10.0
10.00
10.10
10.2270
```

Expected output

```
10
10
10.1
10.227
```

Comment: try using BigDecimal

Comment: best bet is regex for such requirement

Comment: @ScaryWombat The proposed duplicate has a `double` as the input. This question has a `String`.

Comment: @jdphenix so why does OP do `String string1 = Double.valueOf(a).toString()`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Because I didn't read the question closely enough. Oops.

Comment: @jdphenix That's cool, BTW +1 for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 17):

The Java library has a **built-in** class that can do this for it. It's [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Here is an example usage:

```
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal("10.2270");  
System.out.println(number.stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString());
```

Output:

```
10.227
```

Note: It is important to use the `BigDecimal` constructor that takes a `String`. You probably don't want the one that takes a `double`.

---

Here's a method that will take a `Collection<String>` and return another `Collection<String>` of numbers with trailing zeros removed, gift wrapped.

```
public static Collection<String> stripZeros(Collection<String> numbers) {
    if (numbers == null) { 
        throw new NullPointerException("numbers is null");
    }

    ArrayList<String> value = new ArrayList<>(); 

    for (String number : numbers) { 
        value.add(new BigDecimal(number).stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString());
    }

    return Collections.unmodifiableList(value);
}
```

Example usage:

```
ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<String>() {{ 
    add("10.0"); add("10.00"); add("10.10"); add("10.2270"); 
}};

Collection<String> output = stripZeros(input);
System.out.println(output);
```

Outputs:

```
[10, 10, 10.1, 10.227]
```

Comment: I discovered that `stripTrailingZeros()` with also a call to `toPlainString()` results in output that is outside of your spec. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: I did not ask the question lol

Comment: while technically correct it is not useful for me, case in point: `1.23` becomes `1.229999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875`. So yes, no trailing zeros for sure –

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
String string1 = decimalFormat.format(10.000);
```

Comment: This would remove anything beyond the 2nd mantissa digit.

Answer (score -4):

Try regex like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "10.0";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[0]+$", "").replaceAll("(\\.)(?!.*?[1-9]+)", ""));

}

O/P:
10

input :String s = "10.0750";
O/P : 10.075

input : String s = "10.2750";
O/P : 10.275
```

Comment: I don't mind getting downvoted. But I would like to know **why**?

Comment: not the DV, but as someone else said "May not work in every locale. Some use the decimal point as group separators"