# Set BigDecimal precision only if decimals repeating

Tags: java, precision, bigdecimal

I know that I can use `BigDecimal.divide()` method to set a fixed precision:

```
BigDecimal a1 = new BigDecimal(1);
BigDecimal a2 = new BigDecimal(3);
BigDecimal division = a1.divide(a2,5,1); //equals 0.33333
```

But if the division result is exact:

```
BigDecimal a1 = new BigDecimal(1);
BigDecimal a2 = new BigDecimal(4);
BigDecimal division = a1.divide(a2,5,1); //equals 0.25000
```

How can I set the division result so if the division ends with an exact result, it will just give the output of 0.25 instead of 0.25000?

I've also tried to not specifying a precision by doing:

```
BigDecimal division = a1.divide(a2);
```

it succeeds in giving the result `0.25` when doing `1/4`, but when it does division like `1/3` or `2/3` it results in a runtime `ArithmeticException`.

`a1` and `a2` are instantiated from user input.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: You should prefer the [`RoundingMode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) class over passing in integer rounding mode values.  Even if you must use the integer methods for whatever reason, use the constants in `BigDecimal`, e.g. [`BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_DOWN).

Comment: oh I see, I was not really sure which to choose so I just use int instead. But thanks now I understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get an `ArithmeticException` as described in [`BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide-java.math.BigDecimal-) - "*if the exact quotient does not have a terminating decimal expansion*" because to properly represent the result of `1/3` would take infinite memory.  By using [`BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal,int,RoundingMode)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide-java.math.BigDecimal-int-java.math.RoundingMode-) you explicitly set what precision you'll tolerate, meaning any division can be approximated in-memory.

For consistency this version of division always sets the scale to what you specify, even if the value can be accurately represented with less precision.  If it didn't, it would be difficult for you to reason about how precise any future computations using that result will be.

To reduce your precision use [`.stripTrailingZeros()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros--); this effectively reduces the scale to the minimum possible.  Do this as late in the process as possible (i.e. right before you print) to maintain that consistency I mentioned above.

You may also want [`.toPlainString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString--) if you're trying to display these values nicely, since `.stripTrailingZeros()` on its own will display `100` as `1E+2`.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541684/how-to-remove-trailing-zero-in-a-string-value-and-remove-decimal-point/25542023#25542023 (Yes, this is shameless self-promotion)

Comment: It may be worth mentioning `BigDecimal(string)` versus `BigDecimal(double)`, and how the latter can negatively impact formatting output

Comment: @jdphenix OP is using [`BigDecimal(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-int-) which is lossless - I don't see how the limitations of the [`BigDecimal(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-) constructor are relevant to this question, but there's a link to the constructor's documentation if it helps anyone.

Comment: I'm going to convert BigInt value to BigDecimal though so there is no loss I guess. Thanks a lot anyway. It works really well, did not know such function exist..