# Formatting troubles: How to power to number?

Tags: java

What is the best way to format the following number that is given to me as a String?

```
String number = "1.574e10" //assume my value will always be a String
```

I want this to be a String with the value: 1000500000.57

How can I format it as such?

Comment: What's the logic? 1.574e10 !=100050000.57

Comment: Well there's `Double.parseDouble(String)` or `new BigDecimal(String)` but they don't do math for you - 15,700,000,000 != 1000500000.57

Comment: `String.format("%s",Double.parseDouble(1.574e10));`

Comment: This is the logic: Multiply the integer part with 10^9 (would be 10^10 due to `"e10"` but the integer part is already `1` so just use 10^9), and accidentally mistype one `0` to`5`, and round the result to 2 decimal points: 1.574e10 => 1000000000.574 => 1000500000.574 => 1000500000.57. Simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse a `double`, then format the `double`. `BigDecimal.toString()` provides a canonical representation:

```
// Double.parseDouble() also accepts format like "1.574e10"
String formatted = new BigDecimal(Double.valueOf("1.574e10")).toString()
```

Result:

```
15740000000
```

About nicely formatting floating point numbers, see:

[How to nicely format floating numbers to String without unnecessary decimal 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0)

Comment: If uisng `BigDecimal` you have `stripTrailingZeros()` available to you

Answer (score 1):

```
double x = Double.valueOf("1.574e10");
String s = String.format("%.2f", x);
```

The `f` specifier for floating point here gives two positions after the decimal point, with no scientific exponent (e10).

Comment: You need to remove the `0` which specifies padding with 0s on the left because it requires a width to also be specified so `%020.2f` works and `%.2f` works but not `%0.2f`. If you don't mind I will edit the `0` from your answer, because that's the only thing holding back my upvote. So, +1