# No pointation on a Double value

Tags: java, double

The following Code

```
private double roundTheReading(double toRoundValue) {
    double roundetValue = 0;
    if (formatter == null){
    DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    dfs.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    formatter = new DecimalFormat(("#0." + zerosAfterDot),dfs);
    }
    roundetValue = Double.parseDouble(formatter.format(toRoundValue));
    return roundetValue;
}
```

makes a shorting of the double "toRoundValue" because it haves 9 after dot characters and i need only 0, 1 or 2 of them (is set by zerosAfterDot by an Input Method).

Problem is: if zerosAfterDot is "0" the answer should be 5 or 3421. I get the . and 1 Zero everytime (5.0 3421.0).

Dose this have something to do with the Line:

```
formatter = new DecimalFormat(("#0." + zerosAfterDot),dfs);
```

Is the dot in this line the dot i get in my output? If so i could make an If() what checks if the value fter the dot is zero. But i would rather not do that because it would also kill the Dot if the zerosAfterDot > 0. And i want to get around to many if statements.

**TL,DR** How do i get rid of the "." when i dont have numbers following it that are significant?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to nicely format floating numbers to String without unnecessary decimal 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably displaying the `double` value returned from `roundTheReading` which will always include non-significant digits. Instead you can return a `String` and use

```
formatter = new DecimalFormat(("0.#");
```

Comment: The value is used in other ways to, so an String return is not the best way because i need to typecast it back everytime i want to use it. But i can give the UI the string in the getter Method. its a simple answer i didnt think of until i saw yours. Thanks for that!