# How to format a float number in java String.ValueOf

Tags: java, string, format

I have this code:

```
StringBuilder sbp = new StringBuilder().append(
   String.valueOf((temp / 10F)))
   .append(" \260C / ").append(String.valueOf((temp/10F)*9/5+32))
   .append(" \260F");
```

and I get this result:

```
 29.8 C / 85.641 F
```

I want to format the float numbers to show max 1 digit after decimals, 85.6 instead of 85.641

Comment: I think this is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0

Comment: not really, because I needed the format for StringBuilder, but it seems that I still need to make a String.format first and then append to StringBuilder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achieve this using String.format instead:

```
String s = String.format("%.1f C / %.1f F", temp / 10F, (temp/10F)*9/5+32);
```

Comment: Thanks !, now I can append the s to stringbuilder

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example that you can implement in your `StringBuilder`:

```
float num = 85.641f;
num = Math.round(num * 10) / 10f; // pi is now 85.6
```

Comment: How about this, Mario? What do you think Alan?

Comment: All you have to do is cast to a string with `String.valueOf(num)`.

Comment: I need to do this with each number, which makes the code redundant, the answer from Alan is much more compact.