# Truncating 0's from a double

Tags: java, format, printf

I have a JTextField. I need to output there a double. Double is changing all the time (the program is a simple calculator). Possible options for the double are: 10.123, 22.1, 12.00023123, etc.
The problem is that when I use String.format. it always gives me 5 decimal places after the "." Even if those are zeroes.
Is there is a way to truncate those 0's when needed, but leave other numbers if any?

Thank you.

```
screen.setText(String.format("%10.5f", secondNumber));
```

Comment: Read String.format's documentation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to nicely format floating numbers to String without unnecessary decimal 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
screen.setText(String.format("%10s", secondNumber));
```

It will display the minimum number of digits needed to preserve the value but no trailing zeros.

Comment: It doesn't work. The problem with doubles is that they are not always precise. So, if I enter 1.333, the actual double may be 1.33300000111. So, I am getting the last number on the screen. Therefore, I need to truncate the number, I guess, and then print it out.

Comment: String test = "" +Math.floor(secondNumber*1000)/1000;

Answer (score 0):

I Used a combination of Jason's response and this:

```
String test = "" +Math.floor(secondNumber*1000)/1000;
screen.setText(String.format("%10s", test));
```

That actually helped.Thanks.