# Float to string conversion output differs

Tags: java, string, floating-point-conversion

I am trying to parse string to float but it gives me some different output.
Suppose my code :

```
String a = "111111111111111111111.23";
Float f = Float.parseFloat(a);
System.out.println(f);
```

It gives me something like: `1.1111111E20`

In a simple manner, it gives me `111111110000000000000`

How do I get all the data shown? I do not want to truncate the input data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0

Comment: Use Double or BigDecimal instead float has a limitation of smaller size (4 bytes

Comment: Hint: please study a bit more about the representation of numbers using computer systems. If you really rely on "representing data as it is" ... you should really **understand** what that means. And as you are not a newbie: why didn't you do that prior research prior to posting a question here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How to get whole data as it is. Don't want to truncate the input data.

Then whatever you do, don't use a `float`. At *least* use `double`, but even `double` will struggle with that value as IEEE-754 double-precision floating point numbers are only precise to *roughly* 15 digits when expressed in base 10. For greater precision than that, look at [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Comment: Does `BigDecimal` support floating ?

Comment: @user3145373ツ: `BigDecimal` supports floating-point operations, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @user3145373ツ You can check that here: [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Comment: I have tried `BigDecimal m = new BigDecimal(a);` , it gives me `111111111111111110000`. is it expected ?

Comment: I am returning this data to view using json, i think that's why problem occurs. Otherwise I am also getting exact value as it is. But it's json parsing problem i think.

Comment: @user3145373ツ: What parsing library are you using? Does it have the option of getting the value as a `BigDecimal`? If not, you may have to change the JSON to send these values as strings and then parse them yourself after retrieving them as strings.

Answer (score 2):

`BigDecimal` never rounds automatically or loses precision it is highly preferred in calculations.

A `float` is a decimal numeric type represented with 32 bit.

A `double` is a 64 bit decimal number, so it can represent larger values than a float.

You can Use `BigDecimal`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "111111111111111111111.23";
        BigDecimal f = new BigDecimal(a);
        System.out.println(f);
    }
```

**Output**

```
111111111111111111111.23
```

Comment: I have tried `BigDecimal m = new BigDecimal(a);` , it gives me `111111111111111110000`. is it expected ?

Comment: @user3145373ツ no, not expected. Did you try it *exactly* as shown here? Update your question with the code you used and the input and results.

Comment: Okay, I have made it to 15 digits and now it works fine. Thank you.