# Why when I try to store this big number inside a double I obtain this strange result into a Java application?

Tags: java, numbers, double, spring-data-jpa

I have the following problem trying to store the correct output of this SQL query into a **double** variable into a Java applcation.

So I have this **SQL** query:

```
SELECT sum(anagraficaEdificio.imp_tot_ind - anagraficaEdificio.imp_cof) FROM TID003_ANAGEDIFICIO anagraficaEdificio
INNER JOIN TID002_CANDIDATURA candidatura ON (candidatura.PRG_PAR = anagraficaEdificio.PRG_PAR AND candidatura.PRG_CAN = anagraficaEdificio.PRG_CAN)
INNER JOIN TID001_ANAGPARTECIPA anagPartecipa ON(anagPartecipa.PRG_PAR = candidatura.PRG_PAR)
INNER JOIN anagrafiche.TPG1029_PROVNUOIST provNuovIst ON (provNuovIst.COD_PRV_NIS = anagPartecipa.COD_PRV_NIS)
WHERE FLG_GRA=1
```

Performing this query directly on my database (using its client)  I obtain this correct numeric result: **36481888,47**

Ok, so I have implemented it into a Java application (using SpringDataJpa, but I think that this is not important, because it is performed as **SQL native query**) by:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT sum(anagraficaEdificio.imp_tot_ind - anagraficaEdificio.imp_cof) FROM TID003_ANAGEDIFICIO anagraficaEdificio "
         + "INNER JOIN TID002_CANDIDATURA candidatura ON (candidatura.PRG_PAR = anagraficaEdificio.PRG_PAR AND candidatura.PRG_CAN = anagraficaEdificio.PRG_CAN) "
         + "INNER JOIN TID001_ANAGPARTECIPA anagPartecipa ON(anagPartecipa.PRG_PAR = candidatura.PRG_PAR) "
         + "INNER JOIN anagrafiche.TPG1029_PROVNUOIST provNuovIst ON (provNuovIst.COD_PRV_NIS = anagPartecipa.COD_PRV_NIS) "
         + "WHERE FLG_GRA=1", nativeQuery = true)
double getImportoFinanziabileNazionale();
```

that perform the original query.

The problem is that when I call this method by:

```
double risultato = tid003AnagedificioRepository.getImportoFinanziabileMiurNazionale();
```

the value stored into the **risultato** variable is not **36481888,47** (the correct one) but I obtain this value **3.648188847E7**.

Why it contains an E inside it? Is something related to an exponensial notation or something like this? How can I obtain the oringial **36481888,47** value returned by my query into my Java application? Is it related to the use of **double**?

What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: if this is a curreny, no doubles are not prefered for currencies, due to the precission loss. you might want to go with [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Comment: `3.648188847E7` is nothing else than the default String representation of your double. If you need another representation as a String, you may want to look at what `String.format` can do : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0

Comment: The value is correct - the display of the value is not what you expect.  Trust me, it's fine.  It's simply formatting the value being displayed, but feel free to use it in calculations, or use String format to show it differently.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098046/how-to-print-double-value-without-scientific-notation-using-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has an E because it's written in a different format than you are expecting. It's the same number. 36481888,47 (your number) is the same number as 3.648188847E7. The E is for "Exponent", or power of 10 in this case. You can print it the way you prefer.You didn't post your Java code: look up printf or another formatting function so see how you can print it according to your preference. 
http://web.cerritos.edu/jwilson/SitePages/java_language_resources/Java_printf_method_quick_reference.pdf

Comment: It is shown into a JSP page, not by a print in the console

Comment: @AndreaNobili 'print' is a generic term. There need not be a console.