# C# How to nicely format floating numbers to String without unnecessary decimal 0?

Tags: c#

I have the same problem as [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0), but I'm using C#,

How to do it in C#?

(if use Tostring("F") as [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396),  all float number will turn into X.XX, also 0 to 0.00)

Here's an example float numbers

```
232.00000000
0.18000000000
1237875192.0
4.5800000000
0.00000000
1.23450000
```

What I want to turn them into:

```
232
0.18
1237875192
4.58
0
1.2345
```

**Edit**

(I suddenly find what I want to do is more complicate than above but it's too late to modify the question, maybe I'll ask it in another question...)

Comment: Did you try only with ToString() ?

Comment: default Tostring works fine!  (I suddenly find what I want to do is more complicate than above but it's too late to modify the question, maybe I'll ask it in another question...)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `0.############` format. Add as many `#` as decimal places you think you may have (decimals will be rounded off to those many places):

```
string output = number.ToString("0.############");
```

Sample fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jR2KtK

Or you can just use the default `ToString()`, which for the given numbers in en-US culture, should do exactly what you want:

```
string output = number.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `String.Format()` method to remove trailing zeros from floating point numbers.
for example:

```
        float num = 23.40f;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}",num));
```

It prints 23.4

Comment: That's basically the same as writing `Console.WriteLine(num.ToString())` in a much less performant way. Also, `Console.WriteLine` supports format strings directly, so you could do: `Console.WriteLine("{0}", num)` without having to call `string.Format`, but again, `("{0}",something)` as a format string is just an expensive way to call `something.ToString()`

Answer (score 1):

You have to create your own extension method something link this....

> Extension Method

```
namespace myExtension
{
    public static class myMath
    {
        public static double myRoundOff(this double input)
        {
            double Output;

            double  AfterPoint = input - Math.Truncate(input);
            double  BeforePoint = input - AfterPoint;

            if ((Decimal)AfterPoint == Decimal.Zero && (Decimal)BeforePoint == Decimal.Zero)
                Output = 0;

            else if ((Decimal)AfterPoint != Decimal.Zero && (Decimal)BeforePoint == Decimal.Zero)
                Output = AfterPoint;

            else if ((Decimal)AfterPoint == Decimal.Zero && (Decimal)BeforePoint != Decimal.Zero)
                Output = BeforePoint;

            else
                Output = AfterPoint + BeforePoint;

            return Output;
        }
    }
}
```

> Call your Extension Method

```
using myExtension;

namespace yourNameSpace
{
    public partial class YourClass
    {
        public void YourMethod
        {
            double d1 = 232.00000000.myRoundOff();  // ANS -> 232
            double d2 = 0.18000000000.myRoundOff(); // ANS -> 0.18
            double d3 = 1237875192.0.myRoundOff();  // ANS -> 1237875192
            double d4 = 4.5800000000.myRoundOff();  // ANS -> 4.58
            double d5 = 0.00000000.myRoundOff();    // ANS -> 0
            double d6 = 1.23450000.myRoundOff();    // ANS -> 1.2345
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:
decimalValue.ToString("0");

Answer (score -1):

you should use `int.ToString("G")` overload.

Read this -  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wch342y(v=vs.110).aspx