# Remove useless zero after the point

Tags: java, android

To remove useless zeros after the point, I use the following method

```
if (("" + unitValue).endsWith(".0")) {
      return String.format("%.0f %s", unitValue, unitFaName);
    } else if (unitValue < 0.001) {
      return String.format("%f %s", unitValue, unitFaName);
    } else {
      return String.format("%s %s", String.valueOf(unitValue), unitFaName);
    }
```

This method has edited the following values :

```
1.000000 => 1

2 zero after the point and before one
1.001000 => 1.001
```

But can not modify the following values:

But more than two zero after the point and before one can not be modified

```
1.0001000
1.0000100
...
```

That's why I used the following condition to avoid scientific notation top Numbers `(1.0001000 , 1.0000100)`

```
if(unitValue<0.001){
    return String.format("%f %s", unitValue, unitFaName);
}
```

In what way do I modify the following numbers?

more than two zero after the point and before one

```
1.0001000
1.0000100
...
```

I can not use `Decimalformat` or `String,Format` because Digits after the point is not fixed numbers

Comment: `"" + unitValue` Don't do this. Just don't.

Comment: why don't you just check if there's actually a `.` in the number? if there is, then you just start stripping off trailing zeroes. if there aren't, then there's nothing to strip, otherwise you'd be doing `100 -> 1`

Comment: @MarcB I think he's already checking the dot: `endsWith(".0")`

Comment: which would only find `1.0`, but not find `1.00`

Comment: The question was edited "zero after the point and before one"

Comment: @MarcB That's what he's asking :)

Comment: no. it's checking for `dot zero`, which will FAIL if your number is `1.100` the string doesn't "endwith" .0, it ends with .100

Comment: You can use `BigDecimal`'s `stripTrailingZeros` method.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0).

```
public static String fmt(double d)
{
    if(d == (long) d)
        return String.format("%d",(long)d);
    else
        return String.format("%s",d);
}
```

Comment: The second answer in that link is better. Others apparently agree, since it has more votes. --- When the question has already been answered elsewhere, don't copy the answer. Close the question as a duplicate.

Comment: @Andreas that not something I can do now