# How to indent string and double results in Java?

Tags: java

My question concerns the indentation of the results specifically. Some are String and some double. So far I have the following java program shown at the below. I need the following result:

```
Name:             Yoda Luca
Income:           %5000.00
Interests:        Swimming, Hiking
```

I don't want to have to write a prefix for every line. Is there a quicker way to format once for "String" and once for "Double" ?

Program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class forTesting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String prefixName = "Name:"; 
        String prefixIncome = "Income";

        String Name;
        double Income;

        //create a Scanner that is connected to System.in
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter name:");
        Name = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter income for period: ");
        Income = input.nextDouble();

        String format = "%-40s%s%n"; 
        System.out.printf(format, prefixName,Name);
        System.out.printf(format, prefixIncome, Income);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for the record: in the real world you don't use floating point numbers to represent currency. So if you are working with real data about real money, do NOT use TV float here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String format takes format and followed by n number of arguments.

Yes. %f is for double and you can write them in one shot.

```
String format = "%-40s%s%n%-40s%f%n";
System.out.printf(format, prefixName,Name,prefixIncome, Income);
```

And that gives you floating point double. To get it in standard format

[How to nicely format floating numbers to String without unnecessary decimal 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0)

Comment: thanks ANS.  if i then want to format the number to two decimal places, where do i do this?