# How can I remove the zero that appears after the decimal point

Tags: java, android, precision

I have declared two float variables for addition purpose...

So, the user can input 2.2+2.2 and get 4.4
And sometimes the user will enter 2+2 and will get 4.0>> this zero needs to be deleted.

I can't use the round method nor converting the whole result into an integer.

My Actual code is here:

```
holder.txtTotalViews.setText(new StringBuilder().append(new java.text.DecimalFormat("#").format(Float.parseFloat(trendingVideoList.get(position).getTotal_views())/1000)).append("K ").append(activity.getString(R.string.lbl_views)));
```

**I need to calculate total views of video into K format like 10K and 10.5K.
I have problem to remove zero from 10.0K.**

Comment: use `DecimalFormat("#.#").format(solution)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to nicely format floating numbers to String without unnecessary decimal 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0)

Comment: This question does not solve my problem. I need to calculate total views of video into K format like 10K and 10.5K. I have problem to remove zero from 10.0K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Issue is resolved by changing decimal format of the code:
Thanks to @Jyoti now my code:

I need to change my `new java.text.DecimalFormat("#")` to **`new java.text.DecimalFormat("#.#")`** like this.

```
holder.txtTotalViews.setText(new StringBuilder().append(new java.text.DecimalFormat("#.#").format(Float.parseFloat(trendingVideoList.get(position).getTotal_views())/1000)).append("K ").append(activity.getString(R.string.lbl_views)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a common function like this:

```
// No need to re-create decimal format instance. Keep this outside of the function.
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
public String numberToString(float number){
    if(number == (int) number){
        return Integer.toString((int) number);
    }
    return decimalFormat.format(number);
}
```