# How do I get rid of trailing zero?

Tags: java, android, math, expression, calculator

I'm building a calculator app which take up math expressions, parses it and displays the results, for that I use [Javaluator](http://javaluator.sourceforge.net/en/home/).

Something like:

```
String expression = "(2^3-1)";
Double result = new DoubleEvaluator().evaluate(expression);
```

I use two textView for this: one for displaying user input (expression) and the other for displaying the results which are a Double.

Everything works fine but I would like to get rid of the float that is returned after each operation: e.g: `10 * 10 = 100.0`. I tried something like `finResult = result.intValue();` works but is broken for division operations. e.g: `2 / 3 = 0`.

Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: How would you handle `2 / 3` then?

Comment: Would be 0.6. But only zero is retained here

Comment: int value = (int) 6.14; returns 6

Comment: When you do `intValue` or casting, it doesn't round. It truncates: i.e. 0.18927 = 0 and 0.99 = 0.

Comment: @Krul I'll rephrase the question: *I would like to get rid of the float that is returned* - how would you handle `2 / 3` without a `float` then? You can't store `0.6666` to an `int`

Comment: Casting doesn't seem to work. or am I doing things wrong...

Comment: Apparently he wants to truncate it to the tenth's place? He answered my question asking that with `2 / 3 === 0.6`. If it rounded correctly, it would be 0.7, since 0.66 (repeating) always ends with a 7.

Comment: @ifly6 Still, this cannot fit into an `int`. OP said he doesn't want decimal places, but it seems he wants them. A bit unclear to me.

Comment: Honestly, he probably wants [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Comment: Maybe, something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0

Comment: @BackSlash but for int I don't need a float neither.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you're asking here. Could you add some examples of inputs and expected outputs? Right now judging from the title, it seems that you really just need the integer value without decimal places. And for `2/3` the expected result is `0`.

Comment: I just don't need the result be displayed with extra 0 for rounded number, exemple: 100.0 should bve 100.

Comment: @Krul but then you say that `2 / 3` should give you `0.6`. Why do you think you don't need a float here?

Comment: @Krul So you want to remove **trailing zeroes**?

Comment: @BackSlash Sorry If I wasn't clear enoughn e,glish is not my primary language. float is needed for division but what I was asking is how to get rid of the trailing zero

Comment: @QBrute indeed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to nicely format floating numbers to String without unnecessary decimal 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0)

Comment: Solved @ifly6. DecimalFormat was what I needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting rid of trailing zero, you can use `DecimalFormat` and its method [setMinimumFractionDigits](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMinimumFractionDigits(int))(0).

```
DecimalFormat dc = new DecimalFormat();
dc.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);

String finResult = dc.format(result);
```

Comment: This one worked, I just added the pattern. Something like this: `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("####.#######");`