# recursion - how to get a whole number without decimal

Tags: java, recursion, double

```
import java.util.*;
// Algorithm and Java program to find a Factorial of a number using recursion

public class factorial {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");

        int n = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The factorial of " + n + " is " + factorial(n));

    }

    private  static double factorial (int n)
    {
        if (n == 1)
            return 1;
        else
            return n * factorial(n - 1);
    }
}
```

Please enter a number: 
8
The factorial of 8 is 40320.0

Process finished with exit code 0
How to get a whole number without decimal?

Comment: Why do you switch from an `int` to a `double` if you only want a whole number?

Comment: change your code to only deal with `int` variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to nicely format floating numbers to String without unnecessary decimal 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `int` Value or `Double` Value by calling:

```
Double n = new Double(40320.99);
int i = n.intValue();
```

You can directly print the result whatever it's `int` or `Double` Value data type.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`System.out.println("The factorial of " + n + " is " + factorial(n));`

by

`System.out.println("The factorial of " + n + " is " + (int) factorial(n));`

**OR** (better way)

Replace

`private  static double factorial (int n)`

by

`private static int factorial(int n)`

---

**Explanation**

Since your method is returning a `double`, you need to convert it to an `int`, which does not have decimal places. You might want to look at methods of the `Math` class like `round()`, `floor()`, etc.