# Java String format float with and without 0

Tags: java

I have a float number, let's say:

```
Float number = 2.667f;

String.format("%.1f", number)
```

will produce:

```
2,7
```

but in case of

```
Float number = 2.0f;
```

it will produce:

```
2,0
```

is it possible to instruct `String.format` to avoid `0` after comma in case of integer numbers in order to receive for example `2` in the mentioned case.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0 , it exactly solves your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) with `#` symbol:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
System.out.println(df.format(2.1f)); // 2.1
System.out.println(df.format(2.0f)); // 2
```