# Decimal values add Zeros and numbers

Tags: java, math, decimal

I'm building an unit converter app, when I want a value sometimes the answer comes with zeros or nines, like an answer should be 2.6789 it comes out 2.67899999999 or 2.6789000000 and I don't want this to happens how do I fix this?

here's my class:

```
    //celcius
    private String celciusToKelvin(double celsius) {
        double kelvin = celsius *0.000001;
        return String.valueOf(kelvin);
    }

    private String celciusToRankine(double celsius) {
        double rankine = celsius *0.102;
        return String.valueOf(rankine);
    }


    private String celciusToFarenheit(double celsius) {
        double fahrenheit = celsius*0.001;
        return String.valueOf(fahrenheit);
    }

    //fahrenheit
    private String fahrenheitToKelvin(double fahrenheit) {
        double kelvin = fahrenheit*0.001;
        return String.valueOf(kelvin);
    }

    private String fahrenheitToRankine(double fahrenheit) {
        double rankine = fahrenheit *(0.102*1000);
        return String.valueOf(rankine);
    }



    private String fahrenheitToCelcius(double fahrenheit) {
        double celcius = fahrenheit/0.001;
        return String.valueOf(celcius);
    }

    //Kelvin
    private String kelvinToRankine(double kelvin) {
        double rankine = kelvin *(0.102*1000000);
        return String.valueOf(rankine);
    }



    private String kelvinToCelcius(double kelvin) {
        double celcius = kelvin/0.000001;
        return String.valueOf(celcius);
    }

    private String kelvinToFahrenheit(double kelvin) {
        double fahrenheit = kelvin/0.001;
        return String.valueOf(fahrenheit);
    }

    //Rankine


    private String rankineToCelcius(double rankine) {
        double celcius = rankine*9.806;
        return String.valueOf(celcius);
    }

    private String rankineToFahrenheit(double rankine) {
        double fahrenheit = rankine* 9.806/1000;
        return String.valueOf(fahrenheit);
    }

    private String rankineToKelvin(double rankine) {
        double kelvin = rankine*(9.803*0.000001);
        return String.valueOf(kelvin);
    }
```

Comment: `double celcius = fahrenheit/0.001;` ?????

Comment: Why don't you round it upto `N` decimal places?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, bro

`String.format("%.2f", value);`

Btw, this is a duplicate of [How to nicely format floating numbers to string without unnecessary decimal 0's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0s)

Comment: If it is a  duplicate then flag it as such and do not answer.